# How can I get DataMapper to return a sepcific number of elements?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

say I have

```
class MyClass
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :my_property, Text
end
```

How can I make a call to return a maximum of 3 items
Such as

```
MyClass.all(:my_property => "some_text", :max => 3)
```

Where the :max => n would indicate return n items.

I'm pretty sure there exists a built in function for this but I can't find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:limit`

```
MyClass.all(:my_property => "some_text", :limit => 3)
```